# ffmpegのエラーlast message repeatedを止めるオプション質問

Tags: ffmpeg

現在、以下のcommandでライブ映像を録画ダウンロードしています。（録画１時間でファイルを分けています。）

> .\ffmpeg -i "EXAMPLE_URL" -c copy -flags +global_header -f segment
>   -segment_time 3600 -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart -reset_timestamps 1 "EXAMPLE_%d.mp4"

問題はライブ先が終了されると、添付のイメージのようにエラーが発生します。そしてrepeated 回数が永遠に続きます。Ctrl+Cなどで強制終了させると、その時点の録画ダウンロードされた動画ファイルは壊れて(推測)プレイできなくなります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ただ、ライブ先が終了される前にこっちが先にCtrl+Cで強制終了させるとその時点まで録画ダウンロードされた動画ファイルは問題なく見れます。

この問題の解決方法をご存知の方はぜひ教えていただけますでしょうか。（ffmpegのオプションなど）
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

EXAMPLE_URL が HLS ならば max_reload はどうでしょうか。
取り急ぎ60秒分割のニコ生で確認したところ指定回数のマニフェストへアクセスが終わったら正常終了しています。

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#hls-1

```
max_reload
    Maximum number of times a insufficient list is attempted to be reloaded. Default value is 1000.
```

Comment: urlにhlsがあることからおっしゃっているhlsだと思います。上記コマンドの後ろに-max_reload 1 を追加して通常通り録画してみましたが、相変わらず、Last message repeatedのカウントが増加し終了はしませんでした。